# Why can't I download an image from this website?

Tags: website-design, background-image

I tried downloading the blue image in [myheritage.com](http://www.myheritage.com) by right clicking. But somehow I always get the picture with parachute no matter where I right click in the blue area. I downloaded the complete page in firefox and then opened images the blue background was missing. How did they manage to do that? Would like to know the method.

PS: I went through FAQ of webmasters.SE, nothing was said regarding the explicit mentioning of a third party domain name in the question so I am going ahead and posting it.

Edit: How is the image above 955M profiles is also not available to download when we right click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The background of [that page](http://www.myheritage.com/) consists of several semitransparent images overlaid on top of each other.  When you right-click on the page and select *View Background Image* (or equivalent), you'll get the image that happens to be the topmost layer at the spot you clicked.

If you click near the top, you get [this image of a balloon](http://c.mhcache.com/FP/Assets/Images/CompanyHome/pk_company_home_bg_LTR.png?v=2); near the middle you might get [this blue-white gradient](http://c.mhcache.com/FP/Assets/Images/CompanyHome/pk_header_company_home_bg.png?v=3) and at the bottom you'll get [this picture of people on a field](http://c.mhcache.com/FP/Assets/Images/CompanyHome/pk_footer_company_home.jpg?v=3).

I don't think there's any deliberate attempt at trying to prevent users from downloading the images involved here, although certainly some sites *do* use transparent background image layers to try to make saving images more difficult.

Ps. The silhouettes above "955M profiles" are part of [this CSS sprite](http://c.mhcache.com/FP/Assets/Images/CompanyHome/pk_company_home.png?v=2), which I found by inspecting the element in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).