# How to prevent pictures from being downloaded by right-clicking on them or Inspecting the web page?

Tags: images, google-chrome, download, menu, save

When there's an image on a website, it can be downloaded by the following ways:

- Right click on the picture and press `Save As` from the pop-up context menu
- Right click on the webpage in Chrome, press `Inspect`, then find the directory where the image is stored by browsing thumbnails, then right-click on its filename there, and open in new tab, where it can be right-clicked alone to be Saved As

**How can the active downloading of pictures be prevented altogether?**

Regarding the two methods above, I have seen webpages that somehow:

- deny the right-click pop-up context menu (containing `Save As`) from appearing altogether, or
- hide the images from the directory structure that `Chrome / Inspect / Sources` finds so that the visitor cannot save them with
  Inspect.

**How do they suppress the image's right-click pop-up menu, or hide the image file from the `Inspect` directories?**

#### Edit

By download, I mean **direct download** where the visitor actively right clicks on the image and saves it to a specific directory on their computer.

By download, I do not mean:

- **passive download** (the image is automatically cached in some obscure temp folder by the browser just because of viewing the page)
- or **screenshot** (the image is copied to clipboard so that the visitor
  can edit and save it with Microsoft Paint).

#### Environment

Going by what's mostly used, let's assume visitors are predominantly using Google Chrome and we would like to disallow them from downloading images from our site. Obviously we would like to bar any browser from doing this, so we want a method that universally works.

From the host perspective, we'll assume for now Javascript is mostly used for tricks of this nature, but open to answers that achieve the same effect using other languages.

Comment: The user agent (most likely a web browser) will always download the picture. Otherwise it won't be able to display it to the user. - What happens from there is out of your control, you can only annoy users by messing up the user agent's behaviour.

Comment: See also [Why can't I download an image from this website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27003/why-cant-i-download-an-image-from-this-website)

Comment: the question wasn't about background images, but non-background images where the host is able to suppress the pop-up menu from appearing when right-clicking the image

Comment: @user610620 The thing is I can just click on developer tools and entirely circumvent the right-click menu and download it that way. It's not even obscure, anyone remotely competent (think middle school students level of IT competence) is able to do it easily. Whatever you're presenting on the page will and can be easily recorded/downloaded, as you're giving the browser the links to data and saying "go on, download this and show it!".

Comment: the edits in the question clarified already the meaning of download. what are developer tools. which browser are you talking about

Comment: @user610620 Any modern browser in desktop version has a function called "developer tools", it shows you the code of the page given to the client and links to any resources shown on the site (cascading style sheets, javascript scripts, HTML files, any other media content including images and videos). You can, by the way, disable the context menu by using a javascript script binding the "img tag" defining the image, the exct script depends on what you;re using to run your site. (example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery )

Comment: let's assume the visitor does not know how to use developer tools and is not there to circumvent anything. She is simply denied the ability to save any image on the web page by the normal means, which is to right click on images and click on `Save As`. My question is How to disallow the visitor from saving images this way. The question is not how the visitor can circumvent it

Comment: @user610620 the exact way to do it would depend on what exact system and technology you're using to create and run your site. In the end it is usually a javascript script that overrides the call to context menu and disables it for images.

Comment: I think the link in the second half of your edited comment about **binding the img tag with javascript** might be the trick. could you transfer it as an answer so i don't lose it. I will have to see if the example site is using it I guess by looking at its source code

Comment: You can use DRM, i.e. Widevine to encrypt the image as a single-frame video. Level 3 won't prevent screenshots, levels 1 and (I think) 2 will by having the monitor decrypt the stream.

Comment: don't know what any of that is

Comment: @user610620: I'll note that the solution proposed by lights0123 is the only solution that defeats screenshots, though it doesn't defeat digital photos.  Mind you, actually implementing his solution is a gigantic mess (and I don't think it can be done for free).

Comment: @user610620: If the user doesn't know how to use developer tools, they can just use File->Save to save all of the images on the page.

Comment: Is there a particular _reason_ you want to inconvenience your users?

Comment: @Brian And it won't display on possibly the majority of browsers now.

Comment: @Sean to restrict redistribution due to privacy. for example, If the site is for escorts, many of the workers do not want clients downloading their profile photos and misusing them elsewhere

Comment: @Brian let's assume the user does not want to download all the excess baggage (unwanted .html, etc files) that comes along with downloading the entire site in a folder. so the question is about the download of images only. sometimes only a specific subset of the images is wanted

Comment: @user610620: No, I refuse to make such assumptions without a justifying use-case.  You have replied to many such limitations with, "let's assume that doesn't matter." However, you haven't justified these limitations with a proper use case.  In some sense, you are knowingly presenting the community with an X-Y problem, but the SE community is very resistant to answering X-Y questions.

Comment: These limitations aren't being set by me, but observed in sites that have achieved the desired effect

Comment: Note that I tend to right-click to select "Translate to English" in Chrome because the option isn't always available in the address bar, or it sometimes doesn't work from the address bar. Sites that disable right-click are infuriating. Furthermore, downloading images is easy even if I can't right-click or can't drag, etc. For example, in Chrome I can press Ctrl+Shift+I (shortcut for going to the hamburger menu and selecting More Tools>Developer Tools). I can then see the requests to load the images under the "Network" tab. Alternatively I can find them in the HTML and open in a new window.

Comment: @user610620: The problem is that you've asked if it can "be prevented altogether", which can't be practically done (please don't argue that point - just read all the existing answers) but if you changed it to something like "what are the options for preventing the saving/downloading of images for the *majority* of users" you might get some useful suggestions.

Comment: P.S. Even if you somehow found a way to stop the Developer Tools being opened, I could still use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to proxy my traffic and inspect the HTTP requests being made. Oh and _"From the host perspective, we'll assume for now Javascript is mostly used for tricks of this nature"_ - If your page is static then I could also just disable Javascript.

Comment: You could just watermark all your images, either by placing some logo in the corner, or a faint overlay across the whole image.  This is the only easy defense against simply screenshotting the page.  Of course it has its downsides - a small logo in the corner can simply be cropped out or covered by another logo, and an overlay can be somewhat distracting, and could theoretically be photoshopped out, but that's a lot of work for the potential image thief to have to bother with.  It's a tradeoff between how obnoxious you want your watermark to be vs. how much security you want over copyright...

Comment: @user610620 You continue to willfully disregard the basic statement of "if I see the image in my browser it has _already_ been downloaded." You say we must disregard passive downloading (i.e. caching)... why? the image is on my system, I can trivially find it.

Comment: **Cache/passive downloading of an image** is difficult and next to impossible for the average user to locate in temporary internet folders. That's why I'm ignoring any discussion of it. The question is on **active downloading** of pictures.

Answer (score 31):

You can't prevent it, you can only stop people who don't understand coding.

Generally it is done with Javascript which is easy to disable.  Further, it is a trivial matter to take a screenshot of an image.

If you are actually talking about hot linking (displaying images from your server on another site) that can be done via .htaccess.

Comment: there are sites that do prevent it though. right-clicking gives no response (no pop-up menu) on their pages. that is why I am asking how do they do it. As for the second method, the directories the Inspect finds are shown to not contain the images whatsoever, in other words, they intentionally hide them from Inspect somehow. I wouldn't see the first and second methods are done concurrently. It's always one (prevent right-clicking) or the other (hide files from Inspect)

Comment: @user610620 Your question asks whether the downloading of pictures can be "prevented altogether", which as Steve says is not possible. If you want to know how to specifically prevent images from being downloaded via right-click or via inspection, but are okay with the images being downloaded through other means, please edit to clarify, but I don't get the feeling that that is what you mean.

Comment: @user610620 If I really want to copy an image from such a site that has tried these dirty tricks, I just pop open the developer tools and look for it in the list. It is not possible for you, the web developer, to do anything about this.

Comment: See the edits (also above "Edit") for clarification of "download", and techniques employed that I have observed that were somehow able to achieve the desired effect

Comment: @MichaelHampton You don't even need to go into the Developer Tools (which some consider scary); Firefox has a “view page info” section that shows you all the images on a page.

Comment: The long and short of it is that if the user can see the image on your webpage, they've already downloaded it.

Comment: Can't even stop those who don't code. There's a button on my keyboard labelled "prt sc"...

Comment: Heck, you can just save the webpage (Ctrl+S), which also bundles all of the images. One thing I really don't miss about being a web developer is the constant nagging by customers to prevent people from downloading the images or copying the text :)

Comment: Are we allowed here to link to adult sites that contain the right-click block in action? The question was really in locating the line of code.

Comment: Given that this question is now almost 2 years old and you haven't accepted an answer, linking to an adult site is likely not a good idea.

Comment: This answer has not addressed how to prevent the manual saving of images via **Google Chrome's Inspect** tool, so this answer is way overrated.

Comment: @user610620 and you haven't accepted it, so why is there a problem which gives an answer, but it doesn't quite suit you?

Comment: Because there are adult websites that DO prevent right-click saves AND jpegs from appearing in Inspect. Anyone else have a better answer than the 8 here? So far they're all incorrect.

Comment: No, they are NOT incorrect.  Each answer provides information though they may not solve every situation.  Perhaps what is happening at the adult websites you frequent is that the images are displayed in a particular way so that it isn't an actual file that can be downloaded.  Don't limit your thinking to there only being one way to display an image.

Answer (score 25):

By definition, if a visitor can view an image, it has already been downloaded. That's how a web page works. You can however use a variety of tactics to make it more difficult to do so.

As you've mentioned, using JavaScript to interfere with the normal contextual menu is an option. However, that won't work if the user has disabled JavaScript on their browser.

Another method some websites use is to slice each image into several pieces and merge them back together within the browser (using CSS, for instance). Although this doesn't prevent downloading each and all the parts of the picture, it does make it more tedious.

Of course, anyone with some moderate scripting skills and enough determination will be able to overcome those difficulties.

In essence, it's impossible to prevent people/cats/robots to download your pictures but it's possible to make it hard/annoying enough to make it not worth their while.

**Addendum**: To highlight what I and others have numerous times mentioned, it is impossible to completely prevent resources from being downloaded. There will **always** be a workaround. To be clear: **if you can see a picture, you can download it.**

To illustrate: while I can't condone such behavior, some individuals download movies from Netflix, Amazon et al. all the time. Even DRM mechanisms used by mega-corporations with virtually unlimited resources can't prevent a sufficiently determined individual from downloading content.

`<friendly sarcasm>`The best way I know to **almost** completely prevent someone from downloading pictures from a website is to host it on an [air-gapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_%28networking%29) server. However, accessing the website itself would prove rather difficult. `</friendly sarcasm>`

The best you can do is to make it just difficult or annoying enough to deter the average user.

Comment: Serving the image using javascript (from the same source as the right-click-hijacking script to account for those of us who block scripts selectively) would mean js-blocking users don't see the image at all.  A pixellated or blurred version could be loaded as a place-holder instead.  That then means a little poking around to download the image.  With my minimal js skills it would be a small puzzle

Comment: could you show an example by what is meant with "interfering with the normal contextual menu"?

Comment: @user610620 please refer to this question or other similar ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Comment: some webpages also use javascript to replace the context menu with a custom one, ostensibly to add specific functionality

Comment: looking for the described solution that suppresses the context menu from appearing altogether

Comment: Disabling the context menu or right-click via javascript is useless - I can just press F12 to open DevTools and get all embedded images from there. Besides, any non-windows OS might offer other ways, shortcuts or hand gestures to to download images. Android phones or tablets don't have a javascript right-click event, because the OS is optimized for touch screens.

Comment: @ChrisH Load page. Disable JavaScript. Right-click.

Comment: @AndrewMorton true, but if you revoke permissions when using NoScript it reloads the page (this can be turned off, or the page load aborted)

Comment: Are we allowed here to link to adult sites that contain the right-click block in action? The question was really in locating the line of code.

Comment: This answer has not addressed how to prevent the manual saving of images via **Google Chrome's Inspect** tool, so this answer is way overrated.

Comment: @user610620 Please just drop the subject already. If it's on the internet, it can be downloaded. End of the story. If you don't want anybody to download anything, but it on a USB stick, cast it in cement, and drop it on the bottom of the ocean. Please re-read the first sentence of my answer: "By definition, if a visitor can view an image, it has already been downloaded. That's how a web page works."

Comment: Why drop the subject homegrown when there are adult websites that DO prevent right-click saves AND jpegs from appearing in Inspect. Why else would I ask the question when there are actually ppl who pull it off?? Anyone else have a better answer than the 8 here? So far they're all incorrect!

Answer (score 10):

One more trick to make it a little harder, which also works with Javascript disabled.

Use CSS to position a transparent element over the image, so that right clicking it does not show the image-related options.

Or, for added confusion, overlay a transparent image on top, so that right clicking downloads the wrong image.

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GN3GODC20V0D

Comment: when I run your code, i am still able to right-click the image of the cat and select Save As. The pages I've seen wouldn't even respond to a right click

Comment: @user610620 Does it save the cat though, or the overlay? For me it saves the overlay image, which I think will confuse/discourage people. No way to make it impossible though...

Comment: not really pursuing it because the other method denies the pop-up menu altogether

Comment: @user610620: Neither this nor right-click denial are effective, but this is marginally more effective.  Of course, the pop-up approach gives you an opportunity for a, "don't copy my images" javascript alert, if that's important to you.

Comment: Right-clicking on the cat in Firefox (Linux) I get the option to "save page" instead of save image, and doing so doesn't download the image.  But it's easy enough to find in the source of a simple page (e.g. search for common image extensions)

Comment: Are we allowed here to link to adult sites that contain the right-click block in action? The question was really in locating the line of code.

Answer (score 4):

For mitigating direct URL access you would have to implement a token system which allows images to be downloaded only when the page is visited.

When the web page loads, generate a token and save it to a database with a timestamp, for every image on your page append the token like so `image.jpg?token={whatever}`, set images to be handled by a script, have this script check if the token is valid, additionally implement an expiration which does something like "token is not valid if requested 5 seconds after creation". This script will allow you to intelligently say yay/nay to providing the image to the end-user.

This in no way solves the "right-click" issue since web browsers simply give you the cached copy instead of sending a second request to the server.

Comment: this is the first time I've heard about tokens for URLs. what is the full technical term? URL token? what is DB

Comment: @user610620 DB is "database". I don't know if there is a general term for what I've described here. If you're not a programmer then hire a programmer. This solution is not for the faint-of-heart.

Comment: @user610620, you asked about the "token" in the URL.  This is a name/value pair of data being sent to the server, if you pay attention to the URLs you visit, you might notice them fairly often (it depends on how the websites you visit work and what you are doing on those websites):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 2):

To simply disable the Context (right-click menu) at the web page level:

HTML body tag:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Javascript on page:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {
  return false;
}
```

(Reference: recommended site --
https://www.hacksparrow.com/webdev/javascript/disabling-the-context-menu.html)

Comment: This prevents right-click saving the image, but does it (javascript) prevent people from using Chrome **Inspect**?

Comment: @user610620 No, it does not prevent hitting F12 to inspect the page. And user-friendly browsers such as Firefox allow a user to simply hold shift while right clicking to show the browser's context menu instead of showing the webpage's context menu. So in firefox, Shift-Right Click -> Copy Image or Shift-Right Click -> Inspect Element.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're probably looking for is a `javascript` script overriding the call for a `context-menu` on `<img>` tag that does not call the menu and does not do anything.

The exact script depends on technologies used on your site, the most common way is pure javascript (and also the only way independent on the technologies on your site), others might be easier to include and you should specifically ask based on what technologies/frameworks/content management systems are used to create/run your site.

Link for more information, including non-javascript solutions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381795/how-to-disable-right-click-context-menu-in-javascript

Original link from initial comment

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery

Comment: see edit about technologies/environment

Comment: @user610620 The only way to disable the "inspect" thing is to download your images using javascript scripts (which is a way that involves the techniques involving the technologies and creation of the site itself) or including the image data directly into the HTML code of the site encoded in base64. Both are hard to achieve if you're using premade content management systems and not "made to order" site.

Comment: which software in Adobe creative cloud shortcuts web design inclusive of javascript (not just html and css)?

Comment: @user610620 I'm not familiar with adobe creative suite and it's capabilities (I'm mostly a programmer who does specific stuff on large applications including web pages and services) and as such can't help you much. The best question might be on web developer SE mentioning you're not a developer. Ask about including the script disabling the right clinking when creating with the creative suite. And link this question.

Comment: do you just mean SE, I can't find web developer SE

Comment: @user610620 Huh, it seems there is no web developer SE apparently. To be honest I don;t know which SE to use for this specific advice :(

Answer (score 1):

#### Embed the images in a multimedia object.

Back before Flash got rendered obsolete and had its support removed, one popular method for doing this was embedding the images you want to display (but prevent the user from downloading) into a Flash file, preventing the users from accessing the images directly. While Flash is unfortunately no longer an option (for good reasons), there might be other multimedia options like HTML5 that might perform similar functions for your webpage.

Comment: no, the sites that accomplish this leave the images as what they are, images (jpg, png), but access to them beyond viewing is obstructed

Comment: @user610620 How about an example of one of these sites...

Comment: not sure if i will be banned for posting adult related links

Comment: @user610620 It's a good call to not post adult links on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS rule

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on image elements prevents them from responding to click events: right clicking the image will still show a page context menu, but without "save image" or "copy image location" options.

As understood, `pointer-events: none` won't stop downloading images using standard browser tools (such as "page info" in Firefox), but should deter visitors with poorer technical skills from downloading images.

A potential downside of this method is that images that doesn't respond  to pointer events can't be used within `<a>` tags for page navigation: clicking them is ignored. Using the image as the background image of an (inline) block element provides one alternative.

MDN shows HTML support for `pointer-event` was introduced in IE11. If the website supports earlier browsers another solution may be advisable.

Comment: Ppl can disable javascript in tgeir internet browser, but can they disable CSS?

Comment: @user610620 Easily! In Firefox for example, if you inspect an element the style column in browser tools shows the styles applied to an element, with check boxes next to rules to enable or disable them.  My emphasis here was to deter users without particular technical skills.

Answer (score 0):

if screenshot no matter and apart from css or javascript preventions;
to make it harder,
at server side, split your original image too many pieces.
(make 1000canvas for one original image, make each of them draw related part of the image :)
idea:  https://codepen.io/Escu/pen/KVLBYP